# Why does Lark split names into separate characters?

Tags: python, lark

I'm trying to parse a simple text like this:

```
test abc
```

Lark grammar is here:

```
start: test

test: "test" _WSI name _NL
name: (LETTER | DIGIT | "_")+

%import common.WS_INLINE -> _WSI
%import common.NEWLINE -> _NL
%import common.LETTER
%import common.DIGIT
```

Now if I print and pretty_print it, 'name' is split into separate tokens:

```
Tree(Token('RULE', 'start'), [Tree(Token('RULE', 'test'), [Tree(Token('RULE', 'name'), [Token('LETTER', 'a'), Token('LETTER', 'b'), Token('LETTER', 'c')])])])
start
  test
    name
      a
      b
      c
```

Why? I want to have that name as a string, not separate characters...

Comment: What does this have to do with Python programming?

Comment: Lark is a library for Python

Answer (score 1):

**What is happening**

Lark uses different naming conventions for Nonterminals and Terminals. To define a nonterminal you use lower-case. While if you wanted to define a terminal you should use [UPPER-CASE](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/grammar.html#terminals).

Due to this distinction, lark will read the token `name` as a nonterminal, with production rule:

```
(LETTER | DIGIT | "_")+
```

This will result in a tree structure as you have seen in your output:

```
    name
      a
      b
      c
```

**How to solve**

As you actually are not interested in the tree structure and want to have a single token, you actually want to make a Terminal instead. This means changing the token `name` to `NAME` instead. When doing so, you tell lark to read the matched input as a single token, a terminal. Applying this change results in the grammar:

```
start: test

test: "test" _WSI NAME _NL
NAME: (LETTER | DIGIT | "_")+

%import common.WS_INLINE -> _WSI
%import common.NEWLINE -> _NL
%import common.LETTER
%import common.DIGIT
```

Running this will result in the following output:

```
Tree(Token('RULE', 'test'), [Token('NAME', 'abc')])
test    abc
```

Which solves the issue you have encountered.